# Want to Run a function without click any button when application start

Tags: android, function, android-intent, android-activity

I have a function named 'func()'. I want to run this function when application start without clicking any button. just when application load I want to show a massage.that massage in that function. I just want to run that function when app start what will be the code.

```
public class TextViewActivity extends Activity {
  public static EditText etxt;
public final void func(){
    etxt.setText("Massage");
 }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     etxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt2);
     }
}
```

Comment: try my answer it will work for u...

Answer (score 1):

Just put a call to the function on the `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    etxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt2);
    func(); //A call to the function.     
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Simply call `func()` after `etxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt2);` to avoid the NullPointerException.

Comment: I think we also need a way that this gets called only once.  and not more than once.

Comment: My answer addresses this to an extent, but before second load how to clear, the indicator?

Comment: @CodeDroid he dint mentioned to show this message once, Else what you suggested is correct in the case if he wants to show Message once only..

Comment: I guess your right , i inferred this because of the application load comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend subclassing the Application in order to do this.  When the application starts it will go to the main activity.  So I would say just keep a SharedPreference boolean value if it has been set.  If not show the message.

So keep state of the application here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html, just set a boolean. Remember when you app gets called, the activity onCreate always gets called of the main activity, so its just a matter of not calling it again.

Answer (score 0):

try using below code.. *you need to call ur function after you initialize edittext etxt. so it can not cause you NPE*

```
public final void func(){
    etxt.setText("Message");
 }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     etxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt2);
    func();// here your function call. 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class TextViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.etxt2).setText("SMTH");
    }
}
```

In case you really need a function to be called, you can use this:

```
public class TextViewActivity extends Activity {

    public final void func() {
        findViewById(R.id.etxt2).setText("SMTH");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        func();
    }
}
```